# How to evaluate Julia's anonymous functions for a value from an expression

Tags: julia, expression, anonymous-function

I am trying to establish a group of anonymous functions to later call and receive a value from.

Here is a basic working example of the problem I'm facing.

```
expr = :(x+y)
f = eval((x,y,z)->expr)
```

This gives me the following response...
[image]

Then when I try to call it to be evaluated I just get the expression back.

```
f(1,2,3)
```

[image]

I would expect it to return 3 but instead it returns the original expression. How do I get it to evaluate the expression inside the anonymous function as it has been constructed here?

Thanks

Comment: `f = eval(:((x,y,z)->$expr))`. So you construct an expression that defines your function and interpolate `expr` into it.

Comment: Thank you that works great!

Comment: @pfitzseb maybe you could post it as an answer? will be more readable by the others :-)